# Error while using restful API and bodyParser in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I ran the below code and in the command prompt I used the statements:

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"first_name": "Moonis", "last_name": "Rasheed"}' "http://localhost:3000/profile"` 
and

`curl.exe -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d '{"first_name": "Osama", "last_name": "Naveed"}' "http://localhost:3000/profile"`

That is when I am getting the error in this photo. I do not know why this is happening because by my logic it should be adding the data in the profile
[image]

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());


let profile = {
 username: 'azat',
 email: '[reducted]',
 url: 'http://azat.co'
 };
app.get('/profile', (req, res)=>{
  res.send(profile);
 })
app.post('/profile', (req, res) => {
    profile = req.body;
    console.log("created",profile);
    res.sendStatus(201);
 })
app.put('/profile', (req, res)=>{
    Object.assign(profile, req.body);
    console.log("updated",profile);
    res.sendStatus(204);
})
app.delete('/profile', (req, res)=>{
   profile ={};
   console.log("deleted");
   res.sendStatus(204);
})

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to format the `curl` command like this:

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"first_name\": \"Moonis\", \"last_name\": \"Rasheed\"}" "http://localhost:3000/profile"`

Basically, use double quotes around the data parameter and escape the inner double quotes that are part of the `json`.

Comment: I copied the statement and used it, still the same error

Comment: Actually it worked when I enclosed the entire statement in single quotes like this `'{\"first_name\": \"Moonis\", \"last_name\": \"Rasheed\"}' "http://localhost:3000/profile"`

Comment: Although I do not understand why